# Password change for npm user

Tags: npm

On one system I used `npm adduser` and then `npm publish` to create a package.  I want to release another version of this package, but I'm on a different system now.  When I try `npm publish` it tells me that my name or password is incorrect, which is not shocking.

However, I can't figure out how to get it to where I can type my password in again.  When I try either `npm adduser` or `npm login`, it *only* prompts for my Username and Email.  It doesn't prompt for my password, and also tells me that my Name or password is incorrect.  It suggests that I reset the password at  https://npmjs.org/forgot, but I don't need to do this -- I know the new password, I just need to be prompted for it.

I've also tried removing the username from `npm config` via `delete username`, but it still shows up when I do `npm config get`.

There also doesn't seem to be any kind of `npm logout` or another way to end my auth session with npm.

What can I do to log in to npm again with my new password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just remove `~/.npmrc` where old npm configuration is saved and retry command `$ npm adduser`.

see [npm adduser](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser)

Answer (score 1):

If you've changed your npm account password and need to use the npm publish command, you'll first need to log in with your updated credentials.

To update your credentials, you can either log out and then log in again or update your authentication token directly.

Here's how to log out and log in again:

Open your command line or terminal.
Run the following command to log out:

```
npm logout
```

Now, log in with your updated credentials using the following command:

```
npm login
```

You'll be prompted to enter your username, updated password, and email. Once you've successfully logged in, you should be able to run the npm publish command.